# Cant able to display the native language string in code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, api, codeigniter, utf-8

I have written a POST Response API for the android in PHP that INSERTS and GETS the data from MySQL,
and I have designed some webpages for the same concept using CodeIgniter! like posts on Facebook.

The Problem is the data I need to insert/get some language content (i.e; Telugu) the post is uploading successfully from android and web ....but there is an error displaying the string language content from android API uploaded data to WEB &&& Web uploaded data to android.

The string from the database is displaying like this: `à°•à°°à±‹à°¨à°¾ à°µà±ˆà°°à°`
I want it to display like this in native language:  `రిపోర్ట్స్, వీడియోలు.`

### My Codeigniter Web PHP Code:

```
echo $post['postID'];

echo character_limiter($post['postDescription'], '99');
```

[image: API postman response]
(API postman response string for android is getting fine)

Demo URL: http://arunahospitals.com

Comment: you should change your table collation  in utf8_general_ci

Comment: Place meta tag in your view page  <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: ok then upvote my comment for future reference !!

Comment: Thank you for the Suggestion!
I have tried that!.. it displays good while the post is uploaded from web! but not displays while the post data is uploaded from via android API

getting like తన నియ�?�?�?వర్�? ప్ర�?ల�?�?స�? రా�?మ�?డ్రి

Comment: See Mojibake in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

> Set Table Collation into **utf8_general_ci** and add **meta tag** in views

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: tried <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
still getting ప్ర�?ల�?�?స�? రా�?మ�?డ్రి